# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound Heroku cannot find templates

Tags: python, flask, heroku

Just to get this out of the way since this appears to be the number one answer. I have my templates in a template folder that is at the same level as my app.py. The app runs as intended locally. However, when I connect my github repo to Heroku and launch the site I get an Internal server error and the following error. I'm guessing it has something to do with not being able to find the HTML file but that doesn't really make any sense. And ideas?

```
2020-11-29T23:37:27.274573+00:00 app[web.1]:     template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
2020-11-29T23:37:27.274573+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 115, in load
2020-11-29T23:37:27.274573+00:00 app[web.1]:     source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
2020-11-29T23:37:27.274574+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 60, in get_source
2020-11-29T23:37:27.274574+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
2020-11-29T23:37:27.274574+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
2020-11-29T23:37:27.274575+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise TemplateNotFound(template)
2020-11-29T23:37:27.274581+00:00 app[web.1]: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: LoadData.html
2020-11-29T23:37:27.276708+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.102.182.112 - - [29/Nov/2020:23:37:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36"
2020-11-29T23:37:27.278572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=my-mlgui.herokuapp.com request_id=85409ac9-97bc-4fe7-9d07-e23b99cfd0f7 fwd="75.164.50.161" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=914ms status=500 bytes=651 protocol=https
```

Comment: Are the templates folder and its contents committed as part of the repo?

Comment: Just double-checked. Indeed it is.

Comment: Are you sure the template folder/file exists on the same branch that Heroku is using? You said "*connect my github repo to Heroku*". In Heroku, you have to set the branch to use, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OBG8.png). The default branch is `master`, but maybe you commited your template folder/file on a different branch.

Comment: When I deployed the repo I made sure to deploy the branch that has the proper working app. There are several differences such as app.py being named something different and being in a subdirectory. Basically, I would expect it to say something along the lines of cannot find app if it was connected to, in my case, main. Not say it cannot find something referenced in the app itself

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Heroku is picking about capitalization. I had Templates and it needed to be templates.

Comment: It's not just Heroku. It's *always* best to be consistent with naming and assume the system is case-sensitive.