# FastAPI on Heroku cannot find html files in templates folder

Tags: heroku, fastapi

Another question about Heroku and templates, very similar to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066435/jinja2-exceptions-templatenotfound-heroku-cannot-find-templates).

I am using the deploy from GitHub, with a single branch.
My directory structure is:
|
|_app.py
|_templates
----|_default.html
----|_home.html
----|_not_found.html

I am receiving the error

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 126, in load
source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 218, in get_source
raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html
```

The templates are declared in a variable:

```
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory= "templates")
```

And everything work fine locally (Windows + VS Code)

I have tried changing the path of the templates variable to be

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates"))
```

Which also runs happily locally but returns the same 500 error.

Seems to be a common issue with deploying to Heroku!
Total novice with API's and cloud hosting, thanks for your help in advance.